# invalid configuration file in turbo c when using project

Tags: c, project, turbo-c

I'm trying to use my project file in c, but it wont let me do it, it gives invalid configuration file then shows the directory of my project file.

I am using Turbo C simulator for windows 7 64 bit

I already tried to re install it but same error keeps happening, i can run normal files though just cant include my project file.

Comment: Seriously, this junk is over 20 years old and it barely followed the C standard even when it was new. Do you also use a 20 years old computer? If not, then get a new compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do yourself a favor and install some worthy compiler. There are alot of options available on the market. I prefer **Microsoft Visual Studio**.

Some free worthy compilers:

- Microsoft Visual Studio `Express`
- Code Blocks
- Eclipse

Comment: i was using mircosoft visual studio but it gave off some errors, how do you exactly include project file in studio?

Comment: Were the project files in .sln format (visual studio compatible format)?

Comment: .prj format. my files are .c, .h and .prj, where .prj holds the filename of the files

Comment: also keep getting this error

'Debug\t1.pch' precompiled header file is from a previous version of the compiler, or the precompiled header is C++ and you are using it from C (or vice versa)

Comment: Either compile all the code again with Visual Studio or use the compiler which generated the .prj project files.

Comment: Visual Studio is not a strictly conforming C compiler. Do not use it for C projects.

Comment: what would you suggest for C projects?

Comment: @magicianIam Code Blocks or Eclipse IDE with MinGW as compiler. But what you really should ask yourself is why you are doing PC programming in C. There are many languages which are more suitable for that, such as Java or C#.

Answer (score -1):

Turbo C is a old version any way you want a solution how to create a project file without error see this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KAdlaYclkvg

It may help you, follow each and every step carefully it's better not to use turbo c++. use dev c++ or code blocks for better management of project files.